# precalculus - length of the sides of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

Folks,

I'm just about done with the precalculus part of my return to mathematics and have enjoyed relearning much that I had forgotten. I've successfully worked through many problems, but there are a few loose that I'm hoping I can get some help with.

I have no idea where to start with this one, but I'm sure it's something I forgot many years ago...

Two of the sides of a triangle have lengths $4$ cm and $6$ cm, and the angle between them is $120^\circ$. Calculate the length of the third side giving your answer in the form $m\sqrt{p}$ where $m$ and $p$ are integers and $p$ is prime.

The book gives the answer as $2\sqrt{19}$cm, but I don't know how to get there.

Thank You

Gary

Comment: This sounds like an exercise for practicing the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the cosine rule, the third side is $$\sqrt{4^2+6^2-2\times4\times6cos(120)}$$. Note that $cos120=-0.5$, so we have $\sqrt{16+36+24}=\sqrt{76}=2\sqrt{19}$.

Comment: Thank you XcoderX, next detour - cosine rule and then on into calculus.

Comment: You can mark the tick if it helps

Comment: @GaryR please upvote too

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I like to solve this problem with a geometric approach using the Pythagoras theorem.

Start by drawing the triangle with one side as the base. Which side you choose is arbitrary but we need the known angle on it.

[image]

Now extend the base to form a right-angled triangle. We know the hypotenuse already and find the compliment angle ($180 - 120 = 60$). This is enough for us to fill in the other two sides.

[image]

Now we have a big triangle that is right-angled and we know two sides. The base is the sum of the original base and the intermediate triangle. Straightforward to find the hypotenuse using $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$.

[image]

This is the missing length of the original triangle and evaluates to $2 \sqrt{19}$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jay, very nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Do you remember the cosine rule?

$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A$$

This question is a direct application of this formula.

Comment: Thanks Gaurang, yep that was the missing piece of the puzzle.